# Why are circuit results different from theorised?

Tags: transistors, measurement, theory, bipolar

From the following circuit:

[image]

I got the following results in comparison to my theorized calculations:

[image]

Why were my result different to my calculations?

Here is my calculations:

[image]

Equipment used:

- Agilent E3630A
- Agilent 33210a
- Agilent MSO-X2012a
- Agilent U3401A

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided the process and calculations you used to get your theorized values.

Comment: Note how your \$V_{ce}\$ is very small in the measurement. The transistor now operates in **saturation mode**. I suspect that you have an error in the circuit that you're measuring. To investigate, also compare the voltages at base, emitter and collector (\$V_b, V_e, V_c\$)

Comment: I have provided my calculation work flow.

Comment: Do you assume that no voltage is applied to Vin? And are you calculating and measuring at DC steady state?

Comment: Measure the actual parts used as they are not perfect . Connections are not perfect. Take everything into the account and recalculate using the actual values

Comment: Measure the actual parts used as they are not perfect . Connections are not perfect. Take everything into the account and recalculate using the actual values. Multimeters  are not perfect as well

Comment: Just one example: in your calculation you use \$\beta=200\$. Where do you get this value from? What reason do you have to assumne that it is the correct value for your real component?

Comment: letting Rc be too big could result in your measurements. It's so far from theoretical that you're looking for an effect this large, not looking for in inadequately approximated assumption like beta is 100 rather than 200.

Comment: Please list the equipments you used for these sensitive measurements. Lead inductance of probe, cable resistance do play a role.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your measurements are impossible if the circuit shown is correct.

12V / 20kΩ = 0.6mA. Therefore there cannot be 8.03mA going into the Base. However the slightly high Base-Emitter voltage suggests there is, so the '20k' resistor isn't 20kΩ.

According to your measurements, the voltage at the Emitter should be 200Ω*(8.03mA+0.5114mA) = 1.708V, and voltage at the Base should be 1.708V+0.7745V = 2.48V. Therefore current through the 3.3k resistor should be 2.48V / 3.3kΩ = 0.75mA. (12V-2.48V)/(0.75mA+8.03mA) = 1.08kΩ. So the '20k' resistor is actually ~1.1kΩ.

Voltage at the Collector should be 12v-(10.83mV+1.708V) = 10.28V. 10.28V / 0.5114mA = 20.1kΩ. This suggests the '1.2k' resistor is actually 20kΩ.

In other words, the 20k and 1.2k resistor are swapped around.